# Compilation seems not to follow the correct path among different operator= overloads

Tags: c++, class, cuda, operator-overloading

I have two matrix classes, one for the CPU and one for the GPU, say `Matrix` and `CudaMatrix`, respectively. Declarations and definitions are in files `.h`, `.cpp`, `.cuh` and `.cu`. In the `main`, I have

```
Matrix<int2_>      foo1(1,2);
// Definition of the elements of foo1...
CudaMatrix<int2_>  foo2(1,2);

cout << typeid(foo1).name() << "\n";
cout << typeid(foo2).name() << "\n";

// Equality
foo2=foo1;
```

Now, I have no `operator=` overload between a `CudaMatrix` and a `Matrix`, but I have the following `operator=` overload

```
const CudaMatrix& operator=(const CudaMatrix<LibraryNameSpace::int2_>&);
```

between two `CudaMatrix`. What happens is the following:

1. The two `typeid`'s return the correct classes for `foo1` and `foo2`;
2. The above `operator=` overload is compiled and invocated at runtime for the `foo2=foo1` assignment. I would have expected, on the contrary, a compilation error;
3. The result of the assignment leads to a *correct* result for `foo2`!

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and compiling in release mode.

Anyone has some hints on why this apparently illogic behavior occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: Has CudaMatrix an overloaded cast-operator to Matrix?

Comment: No, I have only defined constructors of a `Matrix` from an already defined `CudaMatrix` and vice versa.

Comment: @JackOLantern: And that is what is being used. Copy assignment permits making a new instance of a CudaMatrix from `foo1` via the constructor and assigning to  `foo2`.

Comment: @talonmies Thank you very much. Yes, that was the reason. Interested in converting this comment to an extended answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key to why this works is because you have both a copy constructor and an explicit copy assignment operator. These two things together are what make a seemingly undefined case function correctly. So when you do this:

```
Matrix<int2_>      foo1(1,2);
CudaMatrix<int2_>  foo2(1,2);

foo2 = foo1;
```

what happens is the equivalent of this:

```
Matrix<int2_>      foo1(1,2);
CudaMatrix<int2_>  foo2(1,2);

// foo2 = foo1;
{   
    CudaMatrix<int2_> x(foo1); // copy constructor
    foo2 = x; // Copy assignment
}
```

Note that there are device memory usage implications you should be aware of at play here (ie. two device memory allocations and two sets of whatever API calls you have under the hood).

It is worth pointing out this is not CUDA specific, it is a standard feature of the C++98 object model. You might benefit from revising the [rule of three](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-made-easier-the-rule-of-three/184401400) if you want to learn more about how and why this works (and why seemingly analogous counter examples won't work).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go through the suggested link. What I described in the post is an undesired effect, so I have restored the correct `operator=` overload and now everything works correctly. Again, thanks.